# Read data from NSTask Pipe as it becomes available

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pipe, stdout, nstask

I have this code so far, the goal is to act on certain outputs from my NSTask. Essentially it (My NSTask) is a program that outputs strings to the console over time. I want to be able to say call a method in my cocoa Objective-C app when a certain string is displayed on the console. My thinking is to pipe the console outputs to my app which checks if the string passed warrants an action.

```
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

    self.task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [self.task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [self.task setStandardError: [self.task standardOutput]];

    self.task.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/taskThing";
    self.task.arguments = @[@"taskArg"];

    [self.task launch];


    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:512];
    while ([self.task isRunning]) {
        [data appendData:[file availableData]];
    }
    [file closeFile];

    NSString *taskOut = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"task returned: %@ END", taskOut);
```

This basically "crashes" the app as it the while loop causes it to just keep reading till I kill the NSTasks process. When I do kill the process all recorded output from the Task are then logged. So it kind of works, what I want to be able to do is to act on the Tasks outputs as they appear, the task will continue to run so I cant wait for it to stop before receiving the piped data. Any ideas?

PS. I just saw a mention of `waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify`, hope this helps, looking into it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked more into `waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify`.
In the above code after launching the task I deleted all subsequent lines and replaced with a notification Observer

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

self.task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[self.task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[self.task setStandardError: [self.task standardOutput]];

self.task.launchPath = @"/usr/local/bin/taskThing";
self.task.arguments = @[@"taskArg"];

[self.task launch];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(outData:) 
name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:initialOutputFile];

[file waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

In a new method; "outData:"

```
- (void)outData:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSFileHandle *outputFile = (NSFileHandle *) [notification object];
NSData *data = [outputFile availableData];

if([data length]) {
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Here: %@", temp);
}

[outputFile waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

}

This was all based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408456/why-waitfordatainbackgroundandnotify-doesnt-work-with-the-real-time-monitor-wit)